# Ionic 2 using third party js libs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to use [DrumJs](https://github.com/3epnm/drumjs) in an ionic 2 project and this library requires to run `$("select").drum()`  when the document is ready but even though i have it in a `$(document).ready(function().....)` it runs before the document
Any ideas where to add this in order to run properly?

p.s. I can not import it in my .ts file so i'm using gulp to concatenate some js files that I import via the index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your code using one of the lifecycle events, i.e.:

```
ionViewLoaded() {
    $("select").drum();
}
```

Here is the documentation:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#lifecycle-events

Comment: the problem is that I can't load drumjs from within my .ts file and it doesn't recognize drum() :/ 

tied it and the compliler gives an error right away

Comment: Try to add _declare var drum;_ in the import section inside .ts file

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have to check if DrumJs has a definition file to use the library with Typescript, install that definition package (with file ending *.d.ts*), and then import the library to your script.

**Step by step**

1. To do so, you must install ***typings***, which is like a npm for those definitions. To install it, do ***npm install -g typings***.
2. After installed, check if DrumJS has a definition by executing ***typings search drumjs*** on your terminal. Try drumjs, drum, drum.js, maybe one of those matches your desired library.
3. If the library exists, install it by running on your local folder ***typings install drumjs --save***. If you have any problem, then try ***typings install drumjs --save --global***, or read the documentation of typings if you encounter any further error.
4. Once the definition is installed, you can install the script from npm, running ***npm i --save drumjs*** (i suppose that's the name of the package)
5. Finally, after installing the package and it's definition, import it to your .ts script at the top of the file like: ***import * as drum from 'drumjs';***
6. Use drumJS :D

**Going further**

If you need Jquery for initializing drumJS, then import it in the same way I told you, and write a method *ngOnInit()* in your .ts script.

Then, write the *$("select").drum()* inside it. Somethink like this:

```
class YourClass{
  ...

  ngOnInit(){ $("select").drum() }      

  ...
}
```

Also, check the lifecycle methods for Angular2, there's ngOnInit, but there are also others which may be more suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that i can only import it in the html else i have to make a d.ts file to import in in the code (typescript file) and they load async so there is a race condition I could over come with a setTimeout() but I really don't like this solution, so i decided to drop the try and try to make a new plug-in of my own.

Comment: sadly no. I used a list that the user can scroll... The time pressure of the project didn't allow to build it from scratch. :/